# Remove background in all captcha image with Adobe Photoshop

Tags: background, adobe, captcha, photoshop

How do I remove the background of captcha images using Adobe Photoshop?

The letters and numbers shall be recognizable by OCR. I want to create an action in Photoshop that can be used for all captcha images.

Example captchas:

[image: pic1][image: pic2][image: pic3] [image: pic4][image: pic5][image: pic6][image: pic7][image: pic8][image: pic9][image: pic10]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a adjustment layer Black & White.
2. Duplicate layer and change order to first.
3. Change blend as Color Dodge.

[image: Layer]

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate layer and change order to first.
2. Change blend as suitable one

[image]